# customize theme with get_template_part()

Tags: theme-development

I'm often using the `get_template_part()` function. I read the theme handbook about this function and the codex, but I'm not sure when this function can be useful. For example I've made some modular template parts that will have different functionality, like a swiper slider, image comparision or parallax effects. If I code a child theme manually, I will then modify it to be loaded whit the custom post category or name, but in a scenario where I want to sell my theme, How i can assign a post to this or that template part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_template_part()` is useful for organizing chunks of your site into reusable parts. If you have parts of a larger template that might be used in multiple templates, it's useful to use `get_template_part()` to pull these in rather than have the same markup in each separate template.

#### The real power of `get_template_part()` is that it allows child themes to override these *only* these template parts.

For example, you mention a swiper slider. Using `get_template_part()`, someone could create a child theme and override the swiper slider template part to be a grid of images instead of a slider. All they would have to do is create a template file that's named correctly in the child theme and WordPress would use this new template part instead of the parent theme's template part.

Comment: Perfect, but is this a good idea for a premium theme? Users want to edit all aspects of their wordpress theme from the dashboard, and in my theme tere isn't implemented a page builder.

Comment: Yes, it's always a good idea to support child themes. Always. You're not losing or replacing any other functionality by providing this support, ie you can still support modifications through the customizer and/or options pages.